# undefined symbol - libusb_get_port_numbers

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, ppa

What am I working on that generates this error: librealsense

As clear from the heading, I can't get this error sorted out. I have looked at what other people have suggested, generally along the lines of 'the correct package is not being referenced' or 'you have multiple packages', etc. but the solutions they offered have not worked for me.

The file that generates this has '.so. ...' extension, which I assume is a compiled code. So I cannot force it to reference the correct package, if it is actually the issue. The reason I doubt it is because I have removed completely all libusb packages and reinstalled the one needed. Here is the error I get:

```
realsense-viewer: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librealsense2.so.2.32: undefined symbol: libusb_get_port_numbers
```

Here is some of the info to get people started on:

```
xx@xx:~$ apt-cache policy libusb-1.0*
N: Unable to locate package libusb-1.0.18
N: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libusb-1.0.18'
N: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libusb-1.0.18'
N: Unable to locate package libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2
N: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2'
N: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2'

xx@xx:~$ dpkg -l libusb-1.0*
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libusb-1.0.18
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libusb-1.0.18.tar.bz2
```

I tried to remove libusb-1.0-0 with the intention of re-installing it but

```
xx@xx:~$ sudo apt-get purge libusb-1.0-0 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 upower : Depends: libusb-1.0-0 (>= 2:1.0.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

I cannot remove upower for the life of me, I guess, due to some references made in by ppa list.

```
xx@xx:~$ sudo dpkg -P upower
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove upower which isn't installed
```

I think that I have to remove all those ppas that reference to this package but the list is huge. It may also force some other packages to not work. I do not know how to proceed.

I want the sensor (realsense T265 from intel) to work on my computer without having to retort to a VM. Please consider in your answers that I am not a software engineer or an IT-related guy, so may need to be explained things more. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: What is `librealsense`? Why do you remove `libusb`? It is known that it contains the [`libusb_get_port_numbers` symbol](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=libusb_get_port_numbers+package%3A%5CQlibusb-1.0%5CE&literal=1).

Comment: Yeah it does contain that but it was still giving the same error meaning it was probably not able to find the package... On a number of forums they suggested to completely remove all versions and reinstall the correct one... That is what I have been trying to do but have issues with the unmet dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I think I recently encountered a similar issue and resolved it.

The libusb library referenced by librealsense, was a different one from the one managed by the libusb apt package. It was because I had manually added a different path with ldconfig with a directory containing same filename (when I had tried to use another library named DepthSenseSDK).

```
$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librealsense2.so | grep libusb
    libusb-1.0.so.0 => /opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f80d3545000)
$ ldconfig -p | grep libusb
    libusbmuxd.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusbmuxd.so.6
    libusbmuxd.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusbmuxd.so
    libusb-1.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK/lib/libusb-1.0.so.0
    libusb-1.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
    libusb-1.0.so (libc6,x86-64) => /opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK/lib/libusb-1.0.so
    libusb-1.0.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so
    libusb-0.1.so.4 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-0.1.so.4
```

After removing the additional ldconfig path, the issue was resolved.

```
$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/softkinetic.conf
/opt/softkinetic/DepthSenseSDK/lib
$ sudo rm /etc/ld.so.conf.d/softkinetic.conf
$ sudo ldconfig
$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librealsense2.so | grep libusb
libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f9f45cb8000)
```